# Maya 2018 start-up error

Tags: maya, autodesk

First time running maya 2018 and I got this script error. I did a fresh reinstall after uninstalling maya and I still get the error (I cannot import or export any files). I installed maya 2017 and it was also throwing errors (when trying to import, an error pops up and maya 2017 crashes). I installed python 3.6.2 and python 2.7.13 and tried running maya 2018 again and same error. My computer meets the program's requirements. If you guys have any clue as to what might be causing this and how to fix it please let me know!

> // Warning: file: C:/Program
> Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/scripts/others/mayaHasRenderSetup.mel line 48:
> Failed to run file: C:/Program
> Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/bin/plug-ins/renderSetup.py //
>
> // Error: file: C:/Program
> Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/scripts/others/mayaHasRenderSetup.mel line 48:
> (renderSetup) //  file -f -new;
>
> // Warning: file: C:/Program
> Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/scripts/startup/rememberViewportSettings.mel
> line 29: Active stereo does not work with Aero enabled. Active stereo
> has been disabled. //   // untitled //   commandPort -securityWarning
> -name commandportDefault; onSetCurrentLayout "Maya Classic";
>
> // AbcExport v1.0 using Alembic 1.5.8 (built Jul 13 2016 18:28:45) //
> AbcImport v1.0 using Alembic 1.5.8 (built Jul 13 2016 18:28:45) //
> Error: file: C:/Program
> Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/scripts/startup/autoLoadPlugin.mel line 35:
> initializePlugin function failed (sceneAssembly) //
>
> // Error: Unable to execute igInitialize.mel. //
>
> // Error: Unable to execute xgen.mel. //
>
> // Error: file: C:/Program
> Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/scripts/startup/autoLoadPlugin.mel line 35:
> initializePlugin function failed (Type) //  evalDeferred
> "shaderBallRendererMenuUpdate";
>
> import arnold // Error: Failed to import python module 'arnold' //
> evalDeferred "shaderBallRendererMenuUpdate";
>
> // Error: file: C:/Program
> Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/scripts/startup/autoLoadPlugin.mel line 35:
> initializePlugin function failed (mtoa) //  updateRendererUI;
>
> // Error: file: C:/Program
> Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/xgen/scripts/xgenUI.mel line 512:
> Cannot find procedure "MakeXGenHUD". //
>
> // Warning: file: C:/Program
> Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/scripts/others/supportRenderers.mel line 64:
> The renderer "arnold" used by this scene, is not currently available.
> The "mayaSoftware" renderer will be used instead. //

I also get an error with maya 2016.

> file -f -new;
>
> optionVar -sv colorManagementColorPickerColorSpaceSelection "Rendering
> Space";
>
> optionVar -iv colorManagementColorPickerColorMgtEnabled 1;
>
> // Warning: file: C:/Program
> Files/Autodesk/Maya2016/scripts/startup/rememberViewportSettings.mel
> line 43: Active stereo does not work with Aero enabled. Active stereo
> has been disabled. //
>
> optionVar -sv colorManagementColorPickerColorSpaceSelection "Rendering
> Space";
>
> optionVar -iv colorManagementColorPickerColorMgtEnabled 1;
>
> // untitled //
>
> commandPort -securityWarning -name commandportDefault;
>
> // Warning: file: C:/Program
> Files/Autodesk/Maya2016/scripts/others/retargeter.mel line 27: Failed
> to run file: C:/Program
> Files/Autodesk/Maya2016/bin/plug-ins/retargeterNodes.py //
>
> // Error: file: C:/Program
> Files/Autodesk/Maya2016/scripts/others/retargeter.mel line 27:
> (retargeterNodes) //
>
> // AbcExport v1.0 using Alembic 1.5.4 (built May  8 2014 13:47:10) //
> AbcImport v1.0 using Alembic 1.5.4 (built May  8 2014 13:47:10) //
> Error: file: C:/Program
> Files/Autodesk/Maya2016/scripts/startup/autoLoadPlugin.mel line 46:
> initializePlugin function failed (sceneAssembly) //  // Error: Unable
> to execute igInitialize.mel. //
>
> // Error: Unable to execute xgen.mel. //
>
> // Warning: file: C:/Program
> Files/Autodesk/Maya2016/scripts/startup/autoLoadPlugin.mel line 46:
> Failed to run file: C:/Program
> Files/Autodesk/Maya2016/plug-ins/xgen/plug-ins/xgenMR.py //
>
> // Error: file: C:/Program
> Files/Autodesk/Maya2016/scripts/startup/autoLoadPlugin.mel line 46:
> (xgenMR) //
>
> // BifrostMain plug-in loaded (built Feb 26 2015 18:01:51)
> updateRendererUI;
>
> // Error: file: C:/Program
> Files/Autodesk/Maya2016/plug-ins/xgen/scripts/xgenUI.mel line 198:
> Cannot find procedure "registerXGenPrefTab". //

Little bit of an update, something I found out the output window.

> Could not find maya.utils._guiExceptHook.
>
> Invalid Python Environment: Python is unable to find Maya's Python modules
>
> Python Environment:
>
> PYTHONHOME = C:/Python27
>
> PYTHONPATH = C:/Python27/Lib;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/ATF/scripts;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Bifrost/Maya2018/scripts/boss;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Bifrost/Maya2018/scripts/presets;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Bifrost/Maya2018/scripts;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/MASH/scripts/apiclient;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/MASH/scripts/flux;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/MASH/scripts/googleapiclient;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/MASH/scripts/httplib2;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/MASH/scripts/MASH;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/MASH/scripts/MASHAET;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/MASH/scripts/MayaToAE;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/MASH/scripts/oauth2client;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/MASH/scripts/uritemplate;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/MASH/scripts/flux/ae;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/MASH/scripts/flux/resources;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/MASH/scripts/flux/ui;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/MASH/scripts/flux/resources/icons;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/MASH/scripts;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/fbx/scripts;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/camd/scripts;
>
> C:/solidangle/mtoadeploy/2018/scripts;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/camd/scripts;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/camd/scripts;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/substance/scripts;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/xgen/scripts/cafm;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/xgen/scripts/xgenm;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/xgen/scripts/xgenm/ui;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/xgen/scripts/xgenm/xmaya;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/xgen/scripts/xgenm/ui/ae;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/xgen/scripts/xgenm/ui/brushes;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/xgen/scripts/xgenm/ui/dialogs;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/xgen/scripts/xgenm/ui/fxmodules;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/xgen/scripts/xgenm/ui/tabs;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/xgen/scripts/xgenm/ui/util;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/xgen/scripts/xgenm/ui/widgets;
>
> C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/plug-ins/xgen/scripts
>
> System modules located at: C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\bin\python27.zip
>
> Search path (sys.path):
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\bin
>
> C:\Python27\Lib
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\plug-ins\ATF\scripts
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Bifrost\Maya2018\scripts\boss
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Bifrost\Maya2018\scripts\presets
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Bifrost\Maya2018\scripts
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\plug-ins\MASH\scripts\apiclient
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\plug-ins\MASH\scripts\flux
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\plug-ins\MASH\scripts\googleapiclient
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\plug-ins\MASH\scripts\httplib2
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\plug-ins\MASH\scripts\MASH
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\plug-ins\MASH\scripts\MASHAET
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\plug-ins\MASH\scripts\MayaToAE
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\plug-ins\MASH\scripts\oauth2client
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\plug-ins\MASH\scripts\uritemplate
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\plug-ins\MASH\scripts\flux\ae
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\plug-ins\MASH\scripts\flux\resources
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\plug-ins\MASH\scripts\flux\ui
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\plug-ins\MASH\scripts\flux\resources\icons
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\plug-ins\MASH\scripts
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\plug-ins\fbx\scripts
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\plug-ins\camd\scripts
>
> C:\solidangle\mtoadeploy\2018\scripts
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\plug-ins\substance\scripts
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\plug-ins\xgen\scripts\cafm
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\plug-ins\xgen\scripts\xgenm
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\plug-ins\xgen\scripts\xgenm\ui
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\plug-ins\xgen\scripts\xgenm\xmaya
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\plug-ins\xgen\scripts\xgenm\ui\ae
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\plug-ins\xgen\scripts\xgenm\ui\brushes
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\plug-ins\xgen\scripts\xgenm\ui\dialogs
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\plug-ins\xgen\scripts\xgenm\ui\fxmodules
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\plug-ins\xgen\scripts\xgenm\ui\tabs
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\plug-ins\xgen\scripts\xgenm\ui\util
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\plug-ins\xgen\scripts\xgenm\ui\widgets
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\plug-ins\xgen\scripts
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\bin\python27.zip
>
> C:\Python27\DLLs
>
> C:\Python27\lib\plat-win
>
> C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk
>
> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\bin

Comment: You don't need to install python for maya, because maya is packed with a python version. This error looks like you have a bad installer ? please contact https://knowledge.autodesk.com/contact-support. If it is not a legal version then I am sorry.

Comment: I'm using it as a student. The installers were directly from their website. I can't contact their support because I'm not 'subscribed'.

Comment: cool I think that is a lot of errors, best probably ask here https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/maya-lt/ct-p/mayalt .. good luck man

Comment: Deleted PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH in the environment variables. I can import and export now.